# Pass params to method like many values vs one Object if ibject id Entity

Tags: java, methods, parameters, entity

I have entity

```
Item savedItem = itemService.saveItem(item);
```

And I have method

```
msisdnBuilder.generateDetailsByMsisdn(
                        savedItem.getRulingValue(), savedItem.getDateStart(), savedItem.getDateEnd(), file.getPath(), resolution.getId());
```

whether the transfer method parameters correctly so:

```
msisdnBuilder.generateDetailsByMsisdn(
          savedItem, file.getPath(), resolution.getId());
```

and in method use `savedItem.getRulingValue()` and etc. savedItem  -Entity.

And that will be the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

I will quote you from the book: Clean Code, by Bob Martin:

> The ideal number of arguments for a function is zero (niladic). Next
>   comes one (monadic), followed closely by two (dyadic). Three arguments
>   (triadic) should be avoided where possible. More than three (polyadic)
>   requires very special justification—and then shouldn’t be used anyway.

That means: try to reduce the number of parameters a method has, always. 
So I would say the second option is better, but not the best. Consider wrapping everything up in a new class.